# Relative pronoun qualifies one or more pronouns?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, pronouns, verb-agreement, relative-pronouns

In the sentence "I have a cat and dogs who are dumb", does "who are dumb" qualify only the dogs or does it qualify of the dogs and the cat? Or is it ambiguous?

Depending on the meaning, can I rewrite the sentence as follow?

- *I have [dogs] and [a cat who is dumb].* --> If only the cat is dumb?
- *I have [dogs] and [a cat] who **are** dumb.* --> If both species are dumb?

Comment: It's ambiguous. What's known as an "attachment ambiguity", since it's not clear what noun the relative clause should be attached to.

Comment: You can remove the ambiguity by moving the adjective, eg "I have a cat and dumb dogs", or if they are all dumb you could use "I have a dumb cat and dumb dogs".

Comment: _Both my cat and my dogs are dumb._

Comment: "I have a cat and dogs; they're all dumb."